# R TensorFlow installation error

Tags: r, tensorflow

Trying to install TensorFlow from an R terminal using the command install_tensorflow() I get the following error:

Error: Error 1 occurred installing packages into conda environment r-tensorflow
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\Users\DSA\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\Scripts\conda.exe" "install" "-c" "conda-forge" "--yes" "--name" "r-tensorflow" "tensorflow" "h5py" "pyyaml" "requests" "Pillow" "scipy"' had status 1

I have no idea what I need to fix :(

Comment: have you tried to use the _package manager_ of Anaconda to install tensorflow or r-tensorflow, instead?

Comment: I have the same problem - found respective issue on github: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/277. But it's  not answered there yet